# Merge the registry and windows-registry tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The description of [registry](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/registry) indicates that it's supposed to apply to the Windows Registry, there's a more descriptive [windows-registry](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-registry) as well though.

I would propose to merge [registry](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/registry) → [windows-registry](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-registry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done - Answers now have to be 30 characters long......